# On a concrete example of singular function

Tags: real-analysis

I want to find a non-negative continuous function on $[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and for a.e. $x \in [0,1]$, $f'(x)$ exists and is strictly positive. I want to start with the Cantor function but find it difficult to modify by simple rotation or something alike by preserving almost strictly positive derivative. Any comment shall be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Cantor's function is constant almost everywhere. I think the definition of a singular function is that its derivative vanishes (and exists) almost everywhere. <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_function>.

Comment: I think he's talking about adding $g(x)=x$ to that function to make it strictly positive derivative. But yeah, in that case $f(1)>0$.

Comment: Then how about $x$ minus the Cantor function?

Comment: I suggest to change the title because the resulting function would not be a singular function (at least as I believe it is usually defined). Cantor's function would be the concrete example of a singular's function isn't it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Oh wow, somehow I find that a very strange example, my head hurts...

Comment: @GerryMyerson that should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that if we let $f$ be the standard Cantor function, derivative exists and vanishes almost everywhere, then $x-f(x)$ fills the bill.